# Meaning of "for some other form of what amounts to being its own sake"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> ...not worth doing for the development of high submaximal
>   velocities or for some other form of **what amounts to being** its own sake.

<sup>(Source: *Scientific Principles of Strength Training*)</sup>

I am not sure I know what that last part means

> for some other form of what amounts to being its own sake.

Some form that tries to be standalone or exists solely for its own sake? Not sure If I get it

Comment: For what it's worth, I, a native US English speaker, think that is a horribly confusing sentence.

Comment: I, a native UK English speaker,  do too

Comment: It's very confusing! It contends that doing it for the development of high submaximal velocities is just doing it for its own sake, presumably, because this is not a worthwhile reason for doing it in the author's opinion.

Comment: It is not a sentence, and sounds like a facebook page comment or chat group comment written in great haste.

Comment: @Delyew, can you provide a link to this text? I would love to know more about the mind that can create such a bizarre sentence.

Comment: It's from the book called "Scientific Principles of Strength Training"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I interpret that fragment is

"(whatever we're talking about) is not worth doing for reason #1 and it is not worth doing for any other reason that could be construed as doing (whatever we're talking about) just to do it.

The phrase **"what amounts to being"** means it may seem like it is something different, but when you analyze it, it really is the same as this this other thing.

For example, from [Making Sense of Confusing Antique Furniture Terms](//www.thespruce.com/confusing-antique-furniture-terms-148810)

> Well, since a highboy **amounts to being** a tall chest with a legged base and a chiffonier is a high narrow chest, they're both technically chests of drawers.

The phrase "[for its own sake](//idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+own+sake)" means to do something because doing it is [intrinsically](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/intrinsic#intrinsic__2) valuable and not because there is some other reason to do it.

For example from [Why research for the pure sake of knowing is enough](//www.pbs.org/newshour/bb/why-knowledge-for-the-pure-sake-of-knowing-is-good-enough-to-justify-scientific-research/)

> ...but scientific inquiry is most fruitful when knowledge is sought **for its own sake**, not to justify budgets.